# Laravel on IIS with shared network drive

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I'm running a Laravel app on IIS and everything is working fine except for one thing. We have a large media server on another machine that's housing years of picture and video uploads. We don't want to move that server or its contents for various reasons so we created a mapped network drive to that folder. In Laravel, I have a disc set up this way:

```
       'network' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => '\\\\I:'
        ],
```

(I have also tried the UNC path of `\\\\My-Server-Name\` but that still has the same outcomes)

In my controller, I try to access like this:

```
return Image::make(Storage::disk('network')->get("/Production/Storage/{$request->imgpath}"))->response();
```

When that controller hits, it gives me a very confusing error:
 `Unable to create a directory at \\I:`

so FIRST question: why is it giving me a CREATE error when trying to READ a file?

Next question: if I create a test route in my web.php file that looks like this:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $directories = glob("I:\\" . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    print_r($directories);
});
```

it will return an empty array. HOWEVER, if I put this code into a php file on the desktop and run it like this:

```
<?php
$directories = glob("I:\\" . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
print_r($directories);

?>
```

then use `php my-test-script.php` in the command line, it will return the array of directories.

So some sort of issue is happening between what php is trying to do within the project itself and what it's able to do when running "directly" on the windows system through CLI.

I should also mention that if I change the path in my route test to `C:\` instead of the mapped drive of `I:\`, it works fine and returns the array of subdirectories. So it's only an error with the mapped drive within the Laravel application itself.

I've spent two weeks trying to debug this if anyone can help me.

Comment: `\\\\I:` definitely isn't a valid Windows file path. UNC ought to work better, as long as the IIS user has permission to it

Comment: UNC produces the same error.

Comment: Did you check the permissions?

Comment: can you specify what permissions? I've checked 5000 over the last two weeks. I've created new users, all sorts of stuff. If it's a permissions issue, I need to be guided in what I'm missing.

Comment: Mapped drives are not supported by IIS at all. When you said UNC paths failed, what exactly was the error? UNC paths require the application pool identity has at least read access to the files/folders, which must be configured accordingly on the origin machine by your domain/server administrators.

Comment: In terms of permissions, the UNC file share must be readable (at least) by the account under which IIS runs. What account that is, depends on what account the Application Pool of your PHP site is running under in IIS. If you're also using pass-through Kerberos authentication then the application users's Windows accounts would probably also require permissions to it.

Comment: If you use the Network Service account as the identity, you still need to add sufficient permissions to the shared folder, since both Network Service and Local System appear on the network as the computer account (Domain\Computer$).